# Avoid line breaks at specific places in TextView

Tags: android, textview, line, newline, break

I have a very long string in my strings.xml which is displayed in a TextView with ~10 lines. The string contains an url. The url must be completely displayed in 1 single line. Line breaks before or after the url, but currently it breaks my url after "www."

The url is shorter than the space of the line, that's not the problem.
The TextView looks like this:

```
lalala lululu blabli luli blub
lalabla blu blablo blabl www.
this-is-my-url.com bla.
```

and it should look like this:

```
lalala lululu blabli luli blub
lalabla blu blablo blabl 
www.this-is-my-url.com bla.
```

on other displays it also must not look like this:

```
lalala lululu blabli luli blub lalabla blu blablo 
blabl 
www.this-is-my-url.com bla.
```

this could happen when I try a newline before the link

I hope you see my problem

Comment: put the textview inside a scroll view

Answer (score 1):

```
use android:autoLink="web" in textView in layout.and use \t before or after link.
```

Comment: line break is still after "www.", but the space before "www." became a bit larger, that's all what changed

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert "\n" before and after your url:
Try this:
lalala lululu blabli luli blub lalabla blu blablo blabl\nwww.this-is-my-url.com bla.\n

Comment: then the line before the link could only contain 1 small word on other displays.

Answer (score 0):

add a newline character before the url.

```
<string name="hello">lalala lululu blabli luli blublalabla blu blablo blabl \n www.this-is-my-url.com bla</string>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTest"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I've tried and its working...I'll post the xml layout also. Also check whether there is space between new line character and your string.

Comment: yes it works. But what I tried to say (I've taken the wrong words) that there's another problem with the new line. See my 3rd code chapter. In this case there is a \n too much in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a line break before the last word of a line reach the edge, this solution has worked with me.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50550/154846